# Set Control Properties using strings C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls

I am currenly writing a library that allows my to customize form elements. The code below is a function that gets the name of a control, gets the name of the property and then sets the property of the control but I cant seem to get it to work for some reason. Thanks any help is appricated.

The code:

```
public void SetProp(string name, string prop, string value)
    {
        Form FormControl = Application.OpenForms[form];
        Control mycontrol = FormControl.Controls.Find(name, true)[0];

        PropertyInfo pInfo = mycontrol.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(pInfo.PropertyType);
        var x = tc.ConvertFromString(value);
        pInfo.SetValue(name, x, null);
    }
```

Sample Call:

```
 SetProp("greg", "Text", "hi")
```

Comment: `pInfo.SetValue()` looks wrong. You should be passing in `mycontrol`, not `name`. Try `pInfo.SetValue(mycontrol, x);`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the actual source object into the `PropertyInfo.SetValue` call so it can actually be modified. `PropertyInfo` is basically just information about the property (hence the name), it has no attachment to that specific instance.

You can get it work by changing your call like so:

```
pInfo.SetValue(mycontrol, x);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx